# Plot a Polar Cordinate Node point

Tags: tikz-pgf, polarplot

This question is building from the [elegant solution posted by marsupilam found here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372731/how-to-draw-this-z-grid-graph-of-constant-damping-factors-and-natural-frequencie).  I am trying to plot the a point on this plot with coordinates 0.7201 + j0.5093.  When I put this point in like this

```
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (0.7201,0.5073) {};
```

I also tried

```
\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (35.27:0.882cm) {};
```

no luck.

The point goes to the left bottom corner of the plot.  How to get this point 0.7201 + j0.5093 to show up like this:

[image]

Here is his original solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      height=15cm,
      unit vector ratio = 1 1,
      ymin=0,
      xmax=1.1,
      ymax=1.1,
      samples=100,
      axis lines=center,
      ticks=none,
    ]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,9}
    {
      \def\zet{(.1*#1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{\zet/sqrt(1-\zet^2)}
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x})
        node [at end, sloped, anchor=south,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt]{$\zeta{=}0.#1$};
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2):sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x});
    }

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{.1,.2,...,1}
    {
      \def\a{#1}
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:\a] (180*sqrt(\a^2-\x^2),{exp(-pi*\x)});
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The radial curves do not reach the `y=0` axis. You may want to replace the `\addplot` in the second `foreach` by `\addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:90] ({180*\a*cos(\x)},{exp(-pi*\a*sin(\x))});` Also, you should fix the spacing around the `.` in the zeta labels that is broken with your font.

Comment: So you want `\node[solid, cross out, draw=black] at (axis cs:0.7201,0.5073) {};`?