# How to draw this z-grid graph of constant damping factors and natural frequencies pt2

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, polarplot

This question is building from the elegant solution given by marsupilam found here:

[How to draw this z-grid graph of constant damping factors and natural frequencies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372731/how-to-draw-this-z-grid-graph-of-constant-damping-factors-and-natural-frequencie)

How to plot the other have of this plot (from marsupilam's code given below), so that the new plot is a full circle like this:

[image]

Here is his super code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      height=15cm,
      unit vector ratio = 1 1,
      ymin=0,
      xmax=1.1,
      ymax=1.1,
      samples=100,
      axis lines=center,
      ticks=none,
    ]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,9}
    {
      \def\zet{(.1*#1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{\zet/sqrt(1-\zet^2)}
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x})
          node[at end, sloped, anchor=south,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt] {$\zeta{=}0.#1$};
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2):sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x});
    }

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{.1,.2,...,1}
    {
      \def\a{#1}
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:90] ({180*\a*cos(\x)},{exp(-pi*\a*sin(\x))});
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: could you also please paste the other question's URL in the body of this question? You don't need to add it as a link. The system will automatically prettify it in a few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to do the trick...

Before you ask :

1. there is one line missing, that for `zeta=1`. I suggest you draw it by hand.
2. I am not sure about the values of zeta in the lower part, maybe `1/0.9, 1/0.8,` and so on ?

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      height=15cm,
      unit vector ratio = 1 1,
      xmin=-1.05,
      xmax=1.1,
      ymin=-1.1,
      ymax=1.1,
      samples=100,
      %axis lines=center,
      %ticks=none,
      minor tick num=4,
      xtick distance=.25,
      ytick distance=.1,
      major grid style={thick},
      xticklabels={,-1,,-0.5,,0,,0.5,,1},
      yticklabels={,0,,0.2,,0.4,,0.6,,0.8,,1},
      grid=both,
    ]

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,9}
    {
      \def\zet{(.1*#1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{\zet/sqrt(1-\zet^2)}
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x})
        node [at end, sloped, anchor=south,font=\tiny, inner sep=0pt, fill=white,]{$\zeta{=}0.#1$};
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2):sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x});
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (-180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x})
        node [at end, sloped, anchor=north,font=\tiny, inner sep=2pt, fill=white,]{$\zeta{=}-0.#1$};
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=.35*sqrt(1-\zet^2):sqrt(1-\zet^2)] (-180*\x,{exp(-pi*\factor*\x});
    }

    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{.1,.2,...,1}
    {
      \def\a{#1}
      \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=-90:90] ({180*\a*sin(\x)},{exp(-pi*\a*cos(\x))});
      %\addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:90] ({180*\a*cos(\x)},{exp(-pi*\a*sin(\x))});
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You!  As for the values of zeta on the underside...it starts from 0.9 (from the inside of the unity circle) out to 0.0 on the unity circle.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe so the same as above ? Sounds strange to me...

Comment: Hello, yes, the same as above.  I know that the image is not that great, but if you look closely, the values are repeating.  Thanks!

Comment: Sincerest Thank you! for all your time and help again!  I sincerely appreciate it!